# How to consume Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) by a Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf

When i create a **Windows Service** for getting information from a **Web Application(ASP.NET c#**) for scheduling some task in the client machine.

To consume WCF from the web application. I added WCF reference 
to Window Service project as a service reference, everything seems fine. It 
updated app.config file, added service reference etc. 
it was not working. Any idea will be very helpful.

My Code is shown below

```
string result = string.Empty;

BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://test.com/Service.svc/DevicesService");

using (ChannelFactory<IDevicesService> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IDevicesService>(myBinding, myEndpoint))
{

    IDevicesService wcfClient1 = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
    result = wcfClient1.CheckNetworkConnection(IPLocalHost);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && result.Equals(IPLocalHost))
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Test connection succeeded");

    }
    else
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("No live connection currently available");

    }

    ((IClientChannel)wcfClient1).Close();

}
```

Comment: `it was not working` is not a very precise problem description, at least not precise enough to get any viable answers. Can you be a little more specific? Are you getting an exception? If yes paste the exact message and stack trace.

Comment: When I tested using fiddler,Windows service didn't call wcf method("CheckNetworkConnection") for getting data from the remote server.Now no error showing while running windows service.I didn't have enough knowledge for debugging windows service

Comment: To debug a Windows service, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982636/debugging-windows-services/1982734#1982734.

Comment: Did you check the event logs? Did the service start? Stop?

Comment: what is it CheckNetworkConnection(IPLocalHost) ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it easier, when building a windows service, to build a console application that performs the same work as the service will.  I abstract out the actual working code (e.g. your code snippet above) into a separate assembly and then just invoke it from either my service's start method or the console's main method.

If you move your code above into a console application, does it work?  If it doesn't, can you step through it and let us know where it fails.  And when it fails, what exception information are you seeing?

Let us know and we'll help!