# Is there any reason why a Win Service would not execute functions in an external library?

Tags: windows, debugging, windows-services

I am new to writing Windows Services so this is really strange to me. I have debugged an external library using a WinForm. The external library does some drive mapping, copying a directory structure, deleting the original directory, renaming the copied directory, and then removes mappings.

So, when I write up the service to initialize the external class and start the process, the service doesn't seem to be doing what I think it should be doing. It appears to be doing nothing and completely ignoring what is going on.

Is there anything I am missing? Does the external library need to have any Security attributes?

**Update**
Found out how to attach a debugger, per @Will's comment: [System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982636/debugging-windows-services/1982734#1982734)

**Edit**
It also helps when you copy your app.config file to the correct directory!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a lot to go on here.  First, you can debug your service, which is what you should be doing rather than using a winform frontend to test your code.

The issue is either that your service is not created properly, or that you've got a security issue.

Your service will receive a start message, after which it must run its own code, often on a different thread (a Timer is a common way to do this).

If the service is touching a drive, the user account under which it executes must have rights to perform the operations it attempts.  Try changing the user account under which it executes to your own and see if it starts working.

Comment: Ok, I am running the service (for now) under my own user account. Since I have the rights to map a drive, copy, rename, delete, etc. that should not be a problem. I guess I need to find out how to debug the service, then. That would be a big help and a step in figuring out what is happening.

Comment: I just located a method that will attach a debugger: `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()`

Comment: @IAbstract congrats on finding that method.  You can wrap it in a preprocessor directive [#if DEBUG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) so it only happens during debugging.  Also, the better thing is to give the standard service account (local service or network service) just enough rights to perform the actions it needs.  *Just enough*, being the important part.